# Which is more important for computational neuroscience: differential equations or linear algebra?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling

I know that they are both used in computational neuroscience. However, I am trying to optimize my studying, so it might be useful to know which to focus more time upon, at least in the beginning.

Comment: Hi Logan. Welcome at CogSci. Your questions could be interesting, but it is not clear what you are after. The title and body have two different questions, which require two different answers and there is no context. What are you researching, is there a particular cognitive function e.g., what is the relevance, what is the difference between the equations, and do you have some examples of them? The more context you provide, the better someone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: I will make them separate questions.